# Listview with multiple columns

Tags: image, listview, multiple-columns

I have this code here and it's working fine but now I need a listview with a description texview, maybe a location textview along with a drawable left imageview but I don't know how to do that

```
public class Entreprisesfrag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    public Entreprisesfrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entreprises, container, false);

        final ListView listView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {    
                \\ This is returning the single-line string
                String string = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                arrayList.add(string);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


        @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.recherche_activity_menu_item, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //Do search code here
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId()==R.id.recherche)
        {

        }
        else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.filtrer)
        {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Erreur de connexion ! Vérifiez l'adresse email utilisée et le mot de passe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your simple_list_item_1 layout in order to show the data you need.
Use some sort of divider in order to have separate things in columns.

Comment: You mean like view to separate ?

Comment: yes, you will obtain the same result of having multiple columns in the listview